# Help with cancelling alarms

Tags: android

When user sets alarm and when i want to cancel alarm using a button i have a problem. If the user sets the alarm and then without leaving the app presses the button to cancel it it cancels fine. but if the user leaves the app and comes back and clicks the button cancel the alarm it wont work and it fires an error message.

Comment: added some code above.....      SilentManager.mAlarmManager.cancel(SilentManager.pi); is the thing that keeps crashing if you leave the app and come back.

Answer (score 0):

> SilentManager.mAlarmManager.cancel(SilentManager.pi); is the thing that keeps crashing if you leave the app and come back.

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crash". Most likely, you will find that it is a `NullPointerException`, because your process has been terminated and therefore your static `pi` data member is `null`.

If this is your error, the solution is:

Step #1: Get rid of the `pi` static data member.

Step #2: When you `cancel()`, create a `PendingIntent` on an equivalent `Intent` to the one you used to create the alarm in the first place.

Comment: thats the error thanks for your help