# How to cancel an alarm in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to cancel all alarms other an intent

i am sending stuff in using
`new gofile(this).setSilent(mRowId, mCalendar);`

that then goes to gofile

```
  public class gofile {
private Context goon
private AlarmManager alarm;

public gofile(Context goon){
       mContext = context;
       alarm = (AlarmManager)goon.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


}

public void setSilent(Long Id, Calendar when){
     Intent i = new Intent(gon, anohterclass.class);
     PendingIntent go = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(goon, 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), go);
```

how would i cancel the alarms from another file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with cancelling alarms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779312/help-with-cancelling-alarms)

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `cancel` method, and **you must make sure the `PendingIntent` contains the information than the one you used to set the alarm**.

Comment: like i need the time and id that i set the first one with and put that info into the pending intent?

Comment: Actually, no. The cancel method receives the pending intent only, and the time information is only needed by the `set` method. By the way... haven't you asked this before?